# How to create dynamic collapse from the click of a button?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have no idea how to create a collapse from the click of the button. Can someone help me?

Basically when I click on the "Add" button, I will take data from the screen and create a line with the collapse.

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                                    <!-- foreach para accordion-->
                                    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" style="margin-bottom: 0px !important">
                                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                            <div class="panel-heading" style="background: white !important">
                                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#IdMotivo">
                                                        Teste Titulo
                                                    </a>
                                                </h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="IdMotivo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                                <p style="margin-left: 15px">
                                                    Motivo dentro do collapse
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

[When I click the button, the collapse with the data below should appear.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaycO.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/ux06yzeq/36/

To dynamically add div and data to to the collapse just need to use `append()` with a click.

Click function on Adicionar:

**JS**

```
$('.btn-primary').click(function() {
    $('.collapse').append(`<h4 class="panel-title">
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#IdMotivo">
     New Title
   </a>
 </h4><div class="card card-body">Dynamic Line</div>`)
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! But what I really want is that when I press the button, create a div with the new information. Because it can have "n" lines. Each time I press the button, I add a line with that particular information passed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! May I ask you more one thing?
When I click in the button, can I create a new Title with a new Dynamic Line?
In your code when i click in the button create a new line in the same title.
Can you show me how a create a new title with a new dynamic line inside?